# Quantum information Science PhD position interview

Tags: phd, interview

Recently I got in touch with a professor in the field of quantum information science. I am really interested in the PhD program. After extensively talking with the professor he has agreed for an interview on skype. What should i expect from this interview and how can i be better prepared.

Comment: I'm afraid that we strangers on the internet are unlikely to be able to guess what will be expected by a random professor that we do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More and less:

- Asking personal questions about your motivation to choose the target program.
- Asking about any of your potential ideas, as the main subject of the Ph.D. thesis.
- Asking about your financial status and any need to support.
- Asking technical questions from your undergraduate and M.Sc. level to assess your knowledge.
- Talking about any of your stated stuffs within the CV to check their credibility and truthfulness of your claims, e.g. your expertise to work with an specific software (Be on the edge of your sit and just do not mention the case within the CV, in which you're not proficient).
- Testing your linguistic capabilities within the interview, especially speaking skill, for devotion of some related positions such as teacher assistantship, based on your presented level of integrity.
- ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your points provide a good framework to work upon.